# Data Type of expires column in CakePHPs session table

Tags: mysql, session, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm using database (MySQL) placed session storage in my CakePHP application. As I am using `DATETIME` as data type for time-based database field throughout my application I am eager to use it for the `expires` column as well.

The problem is, that CakePHP won't automatically set the `expires` value in a `DATETIME` column. If I change the datetype to `INT(11)` everything works fine.

I'm wondering if there isn't a possibility to change the data type easily.

Comment: I suspect you may have to write a custom session handler (note the hackery required detailed in [this article](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/PHPdiddy/2010/08/29/how-to-use-a-custom-session-setup-with-database-storage)) in order to make CakePHP use a different datatype.  Note that you would fare better with `TIMESTAMP` than `DATETIME` (the former will store in UTC and convert from/to the connection `time_zone` on insertion/retrieval; indeed, it is actually stored internally as the same integer CakePHP currently uses - seconds since UNIX epoch).